# Getting .Config custom section error only over network share

Tags: c#, config

We have a client Windows application calling C# Web Services.  Everything is in .Net Framework 4.0.

So basically, we deploy Web Services in IIS, and also the client application will be located on the server.  The application will be executed on client PCs via a network share.

Everything works fine, every functionality works ok (Web Services, Windows functionalities, etc).

But we have an error reporting functionality that reads customs definition in the .Config file.  The section looks like this:

```
   <configuration>
       <configSections>
    <section name="exceptionManagement" type="Some.Namespace.ExceptionManagerSectionHandler,Some.Assembly"/>
    <section name="ProductInformation" type="Some.Namespace.ProductInfoManagerHandler,Some.Assembly"></section>
    </configSections>
```

The section will be read only when the application encounters an exception.

When executing the application **locally on the server**, the error reporting **will work fine**, but when **executing the same assemblies from a network share** (even on the same machine with a shortcut using the FQN of the machine and share), I will get this exception (line 5 is my "ProductInformation" custom definition):

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. An error
>   occurred creating the configuration section handler for
>   ProductInformation: Request failed.
>   (\\Server\PATH\Some.exe.config line
>   5) Request failed.

But as I told before, every other functionalitiy will work just fine.  And, of course, I got this at the end of my config :

> loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"

I really don't get it, since basically the code is fine when ran locally, but fails when ran from network share, but all other functionalities will work fine over network.

Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like your remote source is configured incorrectly. Could you share some more info about that part of your configuration?

Comment: Hi Nate, thanks for the quick reply.  What would you like to know?  The only thing I have in my configuration regarding the remote source is as stated in the original post : <runtime>
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't know much about Remote Source, so I'm just going by Google. Have you disabled CAS (code access security)?

Comment: I think that .net 4.0 is not managed the same way with CASPOL by default.  You need to opt in to use legacy CASPOL.  But I maybe mistaking.  When trying CASPOL -security off in a VS 2010 .net 4.0  command prompt, the option -secrity is not recognized.  And as I said, the remote execution works fine.... only fails when trying to read the application config....

Comment: Then back to my original idea, that you made a mistake in declaring where your assemblies are located, or that your access rights are configured incorrectly. Have you tried navigating to the network share in the File System using the user account that runs the application?

Comment: The assemblies are all located in the same directory.  I can navigate the network share no problem.  The assemblies in the config does not have a path in the declaration, since they are located in the same directory.  So I never declare where the assemblies are.

Comment: Are your namespaces and assembly names correct? The most likely culprit at this stage is that there's a discrepancy between the assembly and the config file that gives an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57031/discussion-between-jessy-saint-and-nate-kerkhofs).